# How to formally denote that something is a variable

Tags: notation

For example, let's say I want to say that in notation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, $x$ is a variable in real domain. Is there some way to denote it mathematically? For example if I was to say that $x$ is a real number, I would write $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Is there some similar way to denote that $x$ is a variable in real domain?

Comment: In algebra, sometimes you say "Let $R$ be a ring and $R[t]$ with $t$ begin an indeterminant`` or some variant thereof. Especially in the context when you're dealing with $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ and $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ near one another.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP asks for a notation that isn't any better than saying what $x$ is in plain English. This should not go on for another eleven years.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are looking at functions, you may specify their domain by the notation by$$f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb C$$This notations means that the domain is the reals, and the range is the complex numbers. The general format is $$f:Dom(f)\to Range(f)$$

Comment: I want to denote variable, not function. Is variable the same thing as function?

Comment: In this notation you specify both. What would you need a variable for on it's own?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to do that. The expression 
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
$$ is just short-hand for a function $g$ having some relation to $f$. Another example is indefinite integrals. Suppose $h$ is an integrable function, then
$$
\int h(x)\,\mathrm dx
$$
just denotes the function (up to a constant) which has a derivative equal to $h$. Here you don't write $x\in\mathbb{R}$ or anything.

If you want to specify the domain of the partial derivative, you could write 
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}:A\to\mathbb{R},
$$
where $A$ is an approriate set.